# How to add Custom Control in a form dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program wherein I am adding `controls` dynamically. Control type is based on a value in `database`. For example if the value in `Database` is `Label` then the program creates the control dynamically.

Creating controls dynamically is working great. I am using below function:

```
Type typeFrm = typeof(Form);
Assembly assb = typeFrm.Assembly;
Type controlType = assb.GetType("System.Windows.Forms." + strType);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
Control control = (Control)obj;
return control;
```

then `Control ctrl = CreateControl(strCtrlType);`

Other code is to setup the control location, width, height etc ect.

My question is I have a `custom control` and how will add it to the form dynamically? I tried the function above and change the line:

`Type controlType = assb.GetType("System.Windows.Forms." + strType);`

to

`Type controlType = assb.GetType("CustomCtrl." + strType);`

But its not working. The function always return `null`.

See sample custom control code.

```
namespace CustomCtrl
{
public class CButton : Button
 {        
    public CButton() : base()
    {

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type.GetType("namespace.Type")` only works when the type is present in mscorlib.dll or the currently executing assembly.If not of those things is true, you should use system.type.assemblyqualifiedname

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx

Comment: When i try `Type controlType = assb.GetType("CustomCtrl." + strType).AssemblyQualifiedName;` gives an error `cannot convert from string to System.Type`.

Comment: @Zhyke - He means that you should use `Type.GetType("namespace.Type, assembly.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")`, not `Type.GetType("namespace.Type").AssemblyQualifiedName`. The latter clearly shouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to get the type from an assembly. Imagine you have a class with full name (class name + namespace) `SomeNamespace.SomeClass` within a dll named `Some.dll`:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.SomeClass, 
    Some"); // without .dll
```

So in your case it will be:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("CustomCtrl.CButton, 
    DllWhereCButtonIs"); // without .dll
```